# Having trouble adding mouse event handler in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a game here, and I would like to add event handlers to my buttons to change the time. I know how to do all this, I'm just having troubling actually adding the event listeners to my buttons in my .as file. I have a button named "btnEasy" with the Linkage as "btnEasy" as well.

I am getting this error: "1061: Call to a possibly undefined method AddEventListener through a reference with a static type Class"

Here is my code:

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class MemoryGame extends MovieClip{

    private var firstTile:cards;
    private var secondTile:cards;
    private var pauseTimer:Timer;
    private var score:int;
    private var cardCount:int;

    var numberDeck:Array = new Array(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6);
    public function MemoryGame(){


        //TIMER FUNCTION
        var levelTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 180);
        levelTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerCompleteHandler);
        levelTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
        btnEasy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, easyButtonClicked);
        var seconds:Number = 0;
        var minutes:Number = 1;
        txtTime.text = "1:00";
        levelTimer.start();

        function easyButtonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
            trace("easy button clicked!");
        }

        function timerHandler(e:TimerEvent):void {

        if (seconds > 00) {

        seconds -=1;

        } else {
            if (minutes > 0) {minutes -=1;seconds = 59;}
        } 

        txtTime.text = minutes+":"+(seconds >= 10 ? seconds : "0"+seconds);

            }

        function timerCompleteHandler(e:TimerEvent):void {

            e.target.reset();
            e.target.stop();
            txtTime.text="TIMES UP!";
        }





        score = 0;
        txtScore.text=""+score;

        for(x=1; x<=4; x++) {
            for (y=1; y<=3; y++){
                var randomCard = Math.floor(Math.random()*numberDeck.length);
                var tile:cards = new cards();
                tile.card = numberDeck[randomCard];
                numberDeck.splice(randomCard,1);
                tile.gotoAndStop(9);
                tile.x = (x-1) * 150;
                tile.y = (y-1) * 200;
                tile.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,tileClicked);
                addChild(tile);
                cardCount = cardCount + 1
            }
        }
        trace("Cardcount: "+cardCount);
    }

    public function tileClicked(event:MouseEvent) {
        var clicked:cards = (event.currentTarget as cards);
        if (firstTile == null){
            firstTile = clicked;
            firstTile.gotoAndStop(clicked.card);
        }
        else if (secondTile == null && firstTile != clicked){
            secondTile = clicked;
            secondTile.gotoAndStop(clicked.card);
            if (firstTile.card == secondTile.card){
                pauseTimer = new Timer(1000, 1);
                pauseTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,removeCards);
                pauseTimer.start();

            }
            else {
                pauseTimer = new Timer(1000, 1);
                pauseTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,resetCards);
                pauseTimer.start();
            }
        }

    }

    public function resetCards(event:TimerEvent) {

        firstTile.gotoAndStop(9);
        secondTile.gotoAndStop(9);
        firstTile = null;
        secondTile = null;
        pauseTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,resetCards);
        score = score - 2;
        txtScore.text=""+score;
    }

    public function removeCards(event:TimerEvent){

        removeChild(firstTile);
        removeChild(secondTile);
        firstTile = null;
        secondTile = null;
        pauseTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,removeCards);
        score = score + 10;
        txtScore.text=""+score;
        cardCount = cardCount - 2;
        trace("Cardcount: " + cardCount);

        if (cardCount == 0){
            this.gotoAndStop(2);
            txtFinalScore.text=" "+score;
        }
                }

}   
}
```

The error is at "btnEasy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, easyButtonClicked);"

Any help would be so great! Thank you!

Comment: In the properties for btnEasy that you access via the library, do you see "Export for first frame"?  Also, is this code executed before or after the btnEasy instance appears in the timeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a library symbol called `btnEasy`, this is its class name. That said, you're trying to use `addEventListener()` on a class rather than an instance of a class - similar to how `.round()` and `.cos()` are called through the `Math` class itself rather than needing to create an instance of `Math`.

You'll need to create an instance of `btnEasy` and add your event listener to that:

```
var btn:btnEasy = new btnEasy();
btn.addEventListener( ... );
```

What you're doing is similar to doing this:

```
MovieClip.addEventListener( ... );
```

Comment: Ah yes! Worked perfectly! I should have known.
But now, it's not printing "easy button clicked!" to the output. :/

Comment: If you have an instance of `btnEasy` as a graphic added to the timeline and you're trying to target that, all you'll need to do is assign a different name to that button. Remove `var btn:btnEasy = new btnEasy()` and change the instance name in the properties panel to `btn`.